# fortran modules -- finding where variables are defined/assigned

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I am trying to extract a portion of a large fortran to make it its own program. A particular subroutine imports many modules (only two shown here as an example):

```
subroutine myroutine(aa,bb)
use xx_module
use yy_module

...
end subroutine myroutine
```

There are a lot of variables introduced in the `...` portion that are imported from these modules. Is there a good way (or good tools) to find out which variables come from which module, and so on? Or I have to look through each module to see where each is defined, and then assigned (which may possibly occur in a different module...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SciTools Understand](http://www.scitools.com/) does, amongst many others, just that sort of thing.
Double click on a variable, takes you to the definition. Then search through
occurances.

[image]

Comment: I just gave this program a go but it doesn't seem to understand Fortran 2003 constructs such as type-bound procedures. It's also really expensive.

Comment: @bdforbes - It has been some time since I've last used it; F002 wasn't available at that time. But I remember their support being rather cooperative. Since they claim F2003 support, maybe you could give them a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive - but unfortunately truly expensive for an academic. Maybe at some point in the future... but I am now aware of the existence of such tools and of what type. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

On a UNIX/Linux system:

```
grep -ni "variable" filenames
```

is what I commonly do from a command line. Here, variable is the name of the variable you are looking for, filenames is name of the file (or more files) that you are searching through. This should give you insight right away about what variables come from what module. You can take on detective work from there. When in doubt, type "man grep".

Comment: Thanks - this is of course my default go-to (I usually `rgrep` in emacs or `grep -R -ni -e "expression" *.f`), but was wondering if there was a less "manual" way given the numerous places where "variable" or "expression" shows up.

Answer (score 2):

In case you use eclipse, there is `Photran`, a plugin for working with Fortran projects. I don't use it myself, so I'm not 100 % sure, but I think it should be able to do what you require.

Comment: Thanks - I'm regularly in emacs... but just downloaded eclipse for this. Seems to come with some additional tools but not sure that it does this 'static code analysis' (which I now know my question to be about) exactly...